# How to Change Tablet App to Phone app in Delphi XE8?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

i've created an app in Delphi XE8 for tablets. So if the screen is smaller than 7 inch not everything fits. I do work with layouts and Align properties so everything gets scaled accordingly to the screen size.
I know a few options to make the app useable for phones ass well. But not sure what the best way is.

*Option1:*

Create multiple Views for each size screen.

*Option2:*

Use ScaledLayout to make everything smaller or bigger.

*Option3:*

Use scrollBox.

*Option4:*

Edit component sizes in FormCreate after checking screen size.

*Option5:*

Devide in more Forms.

**So what's the best option or are there even better ways to do this?**

*In the Screen below you can see an example of how my form looks on a 7inch tablet:*
[image]

*In the Screen below you can see an example of how the same form looks on a phone:*
[image]

Comment: This question is too broad, does not have enough information about your application so it is hard to say what is the best course of action, and even if you would include more details, question would still be too broad and answers mostly opinion based.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, but I want people's opinion. I don't have any experience in doing any of these options and hope other people have done this before

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar updated my question with Screens

Comment: The point is that questions seeking opinions are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JerryDodge well if people have good arguments and I agree I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: All I can say is you should have designed it for the smallest possible screen size from the beginning, not the largest.  Have you tried adjusting the `Scale` properties of controls? Presumably of the upper-most controls.

Comment: @JerryDodge adjusting the scale properties does make it possible to view on a phone, only the text becomes really small. And this app needs to be easy to read for more elderly people so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've chosen to use more forms to display all my data, in combination with pop up screens. Along with a scaled layout to automatically scale some fields.